# Grant all syntax for mysql on Server version: 8.0.11 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

What's wrong with it

```
grant all privileges on apip.* to 'root'@'%'  IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'rootadmin';
```

it gives the following error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'rootadmin'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDENTIFIED BY` are keywords accepted by the [`CREATE USER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html) command, not the [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) command.

Comment: So what should i be using then?

Comment: Does the user already exist? Them simply remove the 'IDENTIFIED BY' part. If the user does not exist, run one CREATE statement, followed by one GRANT statement to give the user their privileges.

Comment: Also MySQL 8.0 no longer allows `IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...'`. You can no longer set a password hash manually.